# Resources for learning MF photography with Mamiya RB67 Pro S

Tags: technique, medium-format

I hope this is on-topic!  I have inherited a Mamiya RB67 Pro S Film Camera.
I have used 35mm SLR film cameras in the past and I have a basic understanding of manual photography (gained from Ansel Adams Guide: Basic Techniques of Photography), but I would like some kind of tutorial which shows how to get started and use the Mamiya RB67 Pro S for portrait and still life work.

Comment: Seems to me that there are a lot of tutorials or reviews and impressions that show the workings of the camera on youtube, as well as numerous web pages devoted to it - it is a popular camera. Learn to use the camera first, then try out the subject matter you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first place I would start would be a thorough reading of the [*Mamiya RB67 Professional Instructions*](https://www.pacificrimcamera.com/rl/01200/01200.pdf) which was provided with every Mamiya RB67 when it was brand new.

This manual is quite detailed about camera operation. Attention to detail is important when removing or mounting lenses, film plates, and film backs. If the mirror, shutter, dark slide, etc. are not in the proper positions when doing these things damage to the camera can occur.

There's also an extensive section on available lenses including detailed depth of field charts for each. The final section of the manual has information about various accessories that were offered with the RB67 system. While you probably wouldn't be able to find all of these accessories for sale today, the list would give you an idea what *might* be out there on the used market and what exact terms you'd need to use to search for them on places like eBay.

There is another place where you can view a specific [Mamiya RB67 Pro S Instructions](https://www.usermanuals.au/mamiya/rb67-pro-s/manual?p=1), but I can't find a way to download the entire document as a single PDF rather than use the embedded viewer at that website. Using the "print" button included with the reader and "printing to pdf" only saves the page currently displayed, not the entire document. While the cover indicates it is specific to the *Pro S* model, this manual is shorter and does not include the first section of the more generic manual with basic warnings at the beginning of the manual that every user needs to know before beginning to use any RB67, nor does it include the lens listings with extensive depth of field information for many lenses that were offered with the system.

I did a cursory look through both manuals and didn't really see anything in the [*RB67 Professional S Instructions*](https://www.usermanuals.au/mamiya/rb67-pro-s/manual?p=1) manual that wasn't also covered in the [*RB67 Professional Instructions*](https://www.pacificrimcamera.com/rl/01200/01200.pdf) manual, other than the specifics of the multiexposure interlock on the "Pro S" model. Of the sections that both manuals have in common, the text and illustrations appear to be otherwise identical. It's just that the "Pro S" manual doesn't include everything the more general "Pro" manual does. The main difference between the older "Pro" model and the "Pro S" model that replaced it were the addition of interlocks preventing exposure if the film had not been wound. An additional "multiexposure" lever was added to the film holder which had to be moved to allow a double exposure after cocking the shutter but not advancing the film.¹ The "Pro S" shows two red lines on the viewscreen when the film plate is rotated to *landscape* orientation, the "Pro" does not have an indicator on the viewscreen regarding *landscape* or *portrait* orientation, though it should be pretty obvious by looking at the film holder, which also rotates along with the adapter plate. Both the "Pro" and the "Pro S" also have a place on the left side of the body to store the dark slide so it is not lost when not inserted between the main body and the film plate.

<sub>¹ It is my understanding, never tested by me, than an older film holder from a "Pro" model may be used on a "Pro S", but since the older film holder lacks the multiexposure lever, it is not possible to do multiple exposures using the "Pro S" body with the older "Pro" film holder.</sub>

Comment: I have a ProS, several lenses, all three viewfinders, and multiple roll film backs.  The only significant difference between the Pro and ProS bodies is the addition in the newer model of dark slide and double exposure interlocks (and a dark slide latch in the ProS film backs, to prevent removing the dark slide when the back is off the camera).  Therefore, the Pro instructions in the first link should cover everything that matters, since (IMO) the overrides for the interlocks are pretty obvious.

Comment: Yes, the first manual is more complete, other than the specifics for the multiexposure lever and interlock.